# grails gson view expand children with template

Tags: grails, view, gson

In a gson view one can expand an associated class, as in json g.render(parent, [expand:['children']].  Is there a way to do this such that the child objects are displayed with the _child.gson template?

Answer (score 1):

Currently no, however for instance if the class is `com.foo.Child`, it will look for a template here `grails-app/views/com/foo/_child.gson`. If it is found it will be rendered.